# Script with .vbs (Internet Options\Browsing History\Settings)

Tags: internet-explorer, batch-file, vbscript

I need to create a logon script that changes this option.  It can either be a batch file or a .vbs

"Internet Options\Browsing History\Settings\Check for Newer Versions of stored pages"

Anybody have any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Figure out what registry key this option changes, export that key to a .reg file
2. Use something like this

   ```
   Set oShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell") 
   sRegFile = "C:\Temp\MyFile.Reg" 
   'This line runs Regedit in silent mode
   oShell.Run "regedit.exe /s " & Chr(34) & sRegFile & Chr(34), 0, True
   ```

Or instead you may directly edit registry from your vbs code as described here http://www.activexperts.com/activmonitor/windowsmanagement/adminscripts/registry/

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into that! Prob. what I am looking for....